# Angular factory filter - Can't get data passed to the filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm looking through the Angular docs and I can't better documented stuff.

My problem is as follows:

I have a filter:

```
.filter('filteringService', function () {
        return function (photos, categsList) {
            if (photos !== undefined) {
                var filteredPosts = [];
                console.log('Categories or Selected Categories:');
                console.log(categsList);
                //DEVEL Only, assign a SEARCH value, can't pass the data from the list now.
                categsList = 'people';
                if (categsList === undefined) {
                    for(i=0; i < photos.length; i++) {
                        filteredPosts.push(photos[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log('Trying to push a category slug to search for.');
                    //TASK: Convert in multiple possible selections.
                    filteredPosts = [];
                }

                console.log('Filter returns ' + filteredPosts.length + ' posts');
                return filteredPosts;
            }
        };
    });
```

And I have the template

```
<div class="photos">
    <div class="filters">
        <ul>
            <li><a>ALL</a></li>
            <li ng-repeat="category in categsList">
                <a ng-checked="category[0]" ng-model="category[0]">{{ category[1] }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="photos-list">
        <li ng-repeat="photo in photos|filteringService:category">
            <h1>{{ photo.title }} click <a href="#/photos/{{ photo.slug }}"> LINK</a></h1>
            <ul class="categories">
                <li ng-repeat="category in photo.categories">
                    {{ category.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There's a huge object with posts called `photos` and then there's a category list called `categsList`.

The photos object has the items from the categs list in it. I WANT to be able to filter with the CLICKED element through that list, and maybe multiple filter, but first to pass on the actual filter value to the filter service, **I can't seem to do that.**

How should I do that?

Comment: I know that with checkboxes I'll pass the :selected values only, but really that example doesn't apply here.  I see that with `ng-click` the filter runs again, but the data ain't passed to it. `<a ng-click="category[0]" ng-model="category[0]">{{ category[1] }}</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I managed to pass the filter value, in a dirty way (I GUESS), like this

```
<a ng-bind="category.slug" ng-click="returnFilter(category.slug);" ng-model="category.slug">{{ category.title }}</a>
```

it goes here

```
 $scope.returnFilter = function(theSlug) {
            $scope.filterBy = theSlug;
        };
```

and it comes out here

```
<li ng-repeat="photo in photos|filteringService:filterBy">
```

It's working, but **Is this correct?**

---

EDIT: Also with this way in mind, I could pass an array as theSlug so I can do multiple filtering, and when clicking two times on the same item it would get it out of the array. hmmm

---

EDIT 2:

Let's say the resulting array is under 15 items, could do I run some action in the controller knowing this?

Actually the other way around, could I query from the controller the resulting array that the filter outputs?

I can't $watch the first array, I guess the filter creates a new array and puts those results in page. **How could I watch the resulting array for changes and do stuff in the controller?**