# Angular - how can I watch a filter result array for changes from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, controller

I have a filter that filters with some criteria through a ng-repeat list.

How could I watch the RESULTING array that is made by the filtering service for changes INSIDE the controller?

The full Question and description is here [Angular factory filter - Can't get data passed to the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773992/angular-factory-filter-cant-get-data-passed-to-the-filter) in the first answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about piping your data through a local method like this ?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in catchData((items|cut:max))">...</li>
```

I plunked a full example here http://plnkr.co/edit/2L25wdB6S8GG659H4jPw?p=preview

Comment: Plunker seems to be experiencing some login issues this morning (see their tweeter https://twitter.com/filearts)

Comment: And it's back ! Let me know if it has helped you.