# How can I watch a filtered collection in Angular.JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make an event fire whenever a filtered collection is changed.  The filtered list is attached to the non-filtered list in ng-repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in $scope.filtered = (vm.list | filter:vm.searchText) | limitTo:vm.limit:vm.begin">
```

And here's my event I want to fire:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection('filtered', function () {
            alert($scope.filtered.length);
        }, true);
```

It fires once when the page first loads, before my ajax call populates vm.list, so the alert says 0, but then it should fire again after vm.list gets populated, and every time a change to vm.searchText causes a change to $scope.filtered, but it's not.

I also tried making the $watchCollection method like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('filtered', function (newList, oldList) {
            alert(newList.length);
        });
```

But that had the same result.

I also tried doing as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775011/angular-how-can-i-watch-a-filter-result-array-for-changes-from-the-controller), and it ended up like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in catchData((vm.list | filter:vm.searchText)) | limitTo:vm.limit:vm.begin">

$scope.catchData = function (filteredData) {
            alert(filteredData.length);
            return filteredData;
  }
```

That seemed like it fixed it at first.  It now fired when the API call populated the list, and fired again whenever the searchText caused the filtered list to change.  Unfortunately it made it so changing the begin option on the limitTo filter no longer worked.  Changing the limit option still worked, but not the begin.  Changing the begin does still work with the $watchCollection method.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Too start a watch, you need digest() and since you are using alert, you have to call the apply() method manually which will cause digest() to run and hence your watcher.

Comment: @AayushiJain please cite documentation for that. Have never used `$apply()` or `$digest()` in a watch for anything that was in angular scope

Comment: `item in $scope.filtered` is invalid...there is no `$scope` in the view ...would be `item in vm.filtered =(....)` and watch needs to use function when you are using `controllerAs`

Comment: Create a simple plunker demo with a little bit of data

Comment: Can you provide your controller code?

Comment: @charlietfl `item in $scope.filtered` is _valid_, if field not exist in current scope, it would be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create some variables in view, it added as property to current scope. So, in your case you create `$scope.filtered`, and this added to current scope.
To get it in watch, you just need use same declaration

```
$scope.$watchCollection('$scope.filtered', function () {
    console.log($scope.$scope.filtered.length)
}
```

But better not use variable name like *$scope*, so as not to confuse them with angular variables.

so, you can change it ro simple: *filtered*

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watchCollection('$scope.filtered', function(nval) {
      if(!nval) return; //nval - new value for watched variable
      console.log('as $scope.filtered in view', $scope.$scope.filtered.length);
    }, true);
    $scope.$watchCollection('filtered', function(nval) {
      if(!nval) return; //nval - new value for watched variable
      console.log('as filtered in view', $scope.filtered.length);
    }, true);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" data-ng-model="search" />
  <h3>as $scope.filtered</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in $scope.filtered = ([11,12,23]| filter:search)">item_{{item}} from {{$scope.filtered}}</div>
  <h3>as filtered</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in filtered = ([11,12,23]| filter:search)">item_{{item}} from {{filtered}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm new to using $scope, and the documentation I read made it sound like only variables declared in the controller as properties on $scope could be watched.  Apparently that's totally not true.  So I commented out the declaration of $scope.filtered = []; and changed my ng-repeat to this:<tr ng-repeat="item in (filtered = (vm.list | filter:vm.searchText)) | limitTo:vm.limit:vm.begin">.  Then it worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SurgeBinder, you can watch any `$scope` field, not matter where and when it declared, also you can pass function as `watchExpression` parameter, so you can watch not only $scope fields. see more in [doc and samples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use a function to return the filtered list and set object equality to true.

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return $scope.filtered;
}, function (newList) {
  alert(newList.length);
}, true);
```